# Audio player not showing in IE9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, html5-audio

In other browsers I see the audio player, but in IE9 I see this:

[image: blank player]

http://adamkobrin.com/test1.php

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>test1</title>
<style type="text/css">
audio {
    width: 300px;
    height: 40px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<audio controls preload="auto">
    <source src="audio/crickets.mp3" />
    <source src="audio/crickets.ogg" />
Your browser does not support the audio tag.
</audio>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

Comment: It is rendering in IE9 on my side, just not the full player. 
Weird

Comment: What do you mean "not the full player"? Are you seeing the image on my  original post? BTW, I did add the <meta> tag but to no avail...

Comment: Have you checked your security-settings in IE? I encountered this issue when I set the security-level to 'high'. Setting it back to 'medium' resolved the issue.
The (not so) funny thing is that I could not find a way to customize the 'high'-security-level so that html5 audio is enabled again...

Answer (score 1):

I think what Lews means is that he sees only the Play/Pause button and not the full audio controls for IE9 (that is the volume, mute, progress bar etc.) I only see the Play/Pause button too.
If you're seeing the image displayed in your original post, you might want to check that your server has a mime mapping of audio/mpeg for the mp3 extension. I used to see that same image for one of my programs and overriding the mime mapping for mp3 fixed the issue. I was then able to see the full audio controls and play the audio just fine.